# How to select a few characters of a string from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter, truncate

I am trying to implement a preview for various articles, the preview should be a small part of the full article to give the reader and idea of the content.

My current solution is to load all content as text and display it in a div with a max-width of `300px` and overflow hidden. While this does work it does not seem like the best solution.

I though that maybe selecting a part of the content using mysql would be an option. How would I approach getting a preview, should I just get N characters or does MYSQL have more tailored functions for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Text Helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html) that come up with codeigniter. There are 2 functions that can use to achieve your desired result. I prefer `character_limiter()`.

- `character_limiter()`
  Truncates a string to the number of characters specified. It maintains the integrity of words

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";
$string = character_limiter($string, 20);
// Returns:  Here is a nice text string
```

- `word_limiter()`
  Truncates a string to the number of words specified

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";
$string = word_limiter($string, 4);
// Returns:  Here is a nice
```